# PHP Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in

Tags: php

I got this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home/xxxx/public_html/init.php on line 98
```

and the code:

```
$stats['statTodaysLinks']   = $db->GetOne("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `{$tables['link']['name']}` WHERE `DATE_ADDED` LIKE '".date ('Y-m-d', TIMENOW)."%'");
```

Comment: As the error message states, `TIMENOW` is a `string`, not a `long`.

Comment: And what is unclear to you?

Comment: Or TIMENOW is undefined, therefore PHP converts it to a string.

Comment: if you want to get current time, remove `TIMENOW` in `date` function

Answer (score 2):

It's your TIMENOW constant that's causing the problem by the looks of it, there's no need for it as the function will automatically use the current time if you don't supply anything.

So instead of `date ('Y-m-d', TIMENOW)` use `date ('Y-m-d')`.